# Перекодировка строк в читабельный вид

Tags: c#, .net, кодировка

У меня есть данные в неизвестной мне кодировке. Предположительно (почти уверен) это windows-1251 или 1252. Известные мне способы перекодировки типа `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(str))` не дают результата (строка меняется, но остается нечитабельной). Если интересно вот например так выглядит строка при выводе в консоли: `ia?niiae`, а так если записать ее в файл: `ïåðñîíàë` (это без перекодировки). Подскажите что еще попробовать?

Comment: _У меня есть данные_ - эти данные где: в файле, в массиве байтов или уже в строке System.String?

Comment: Строки в дотнете могут иметь только одну кодировку: UTF-16. Все другие кодировки могут быть представлены только в виде массива байтов. В файл или поток, естественно, тоже можно помещать строки в любой кодировке именно в виде массива байтов.

Answer (score 1):

Артемий  лебедев декодер в инете посмотри. заведи туда он покажет что за кодировка. а потом уже encoding

Comment: Ну он вроде показал что: CP1252 -> CP1251. И правда - так становится читабельно. А теперь как мне это перегнать в utf-8? Вот так я расшифровал до читабельного вида: `Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(str))`, а теперь я дополнительно еще хочу перегнать это в юникод (так оно посовременнее и чтоб проблем таких больше не было). Я пытаюсь на полученную строку делать аналогично: `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(str))`, но получаю лишь кучу вопросительных знаков. В чем проблема?

Comment: Вам же показано, что CP1252 -> CP1251. А вы делаете `GetEncoding(1251)`

Comment: @Bulson я все правильно делаю. Я же сказал это уже к перекодированной строке применено.

Comment: @Bulson Может так вам будет понятнее: http://skrinshoter.ru/i/260119/5ZFnFMZC.png